# C program generating compile warnings related to Xcode despite not using it

Tags: c, xcode, macos

In a C project I'm working on, I have some fairly innocuous `return NULL;` statements. This is causing some strange compile warnings that I don't quite understand:

```
warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning 'void *' from a function with result type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]
    return NULL;
           ^~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types/_null.h:29:15: note: expanded from
  macro 'NULL'
#define NULL  __DARWIN_NULL
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/include/sys/_types.h:52:23: note: expanded from macro
  '__DARWIN_NULL'
#define __DARWIN_NULL ((void *)0)
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

As far as I can tell, no where in my project do I include anything obviously associated with Xcode, nor am I even developing in Xcode (I'm editing in Sublime Text 2 and compiling with gcc if it matters), yet for some reason NULL seems to be interpreted by my environment the way Xcode defines it. This is a weird thing to diagnose, too, because almost every development issue people have with Xcode is, believe or not, related to developing *in* Xcode. But since I'm not doing that, where could this warning be coming from?

Comment: `warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion returning 'void *' from a function with result type 'int' [-Wint-conversion]`. This is pretty self explanatory. Guess why I can't be more specific? Hint: it's because you didn't post any code.

Answer (score 2):

The function is declared as returning `int` (or maybe doesn't have a specific return type specified, in which case, `int` is assumed), yet you are returning `NULL` from that function.

If the function should return `int`, then `NULL` is not a suitable return value (perhaps `0` might be a better choice). If the function *should* return a pointer type, make sure the function is declared as returning one, and not declared as returning `int`.